# Access query to return several similar records when one is flagged

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Database with a table [tblPriData] that contains the following pertinent fields populated with data:

- *[tblPriData].[priStkCode]* - name of the item
- *[tblPriData].[priDate]* - date of item’s purchase
- *[tblPriData].[priOrigPrice]* - cost per item at time of purchase
- *[tblPriData].[priPriceConfirmed]* – a boolean, if set to TRUE it confirms that a purchase price is no longer an estimate but an actual amount

When new transactions are entered into the table, their [priOrigPrice] is initially estimated based off historical values and their [priPriceConfirmed] is set to FALSE. Later in the month when the actual invoices arrive, the [priOrigPrice] is adjusted to the proper amount and the [priPriceConfirmed] is then set to TRUE.

**How do I run a query that will display *all* of the records for matching [priStkCode] if the [priPriceConfirmed] is set to FALSE for *any* of the entries that share the matching [priStkCode]?**

As an illustration, if the table contained the following data:

```
priStkCode      priDate     priOrigPrice       priPriceConfirmed
AAA             1/1/13      $100                Yes
AAA             2/1/13      $150                Yes
AAA             3/1/13      $150                No
BBB             1/1/13      $10             Yes
BBB             2/1/13      $10             Yes
CCC             3/1/13      $45             No
```

The query would return all of the AAA entries and all of the CCC entries:

```
priStkCode      priDate     priOrigPrice       priPriceConfirmed
AAA             1/1/13      $100                Yes
AAA             2/1/13      $150                Yes
AAA             3/1/13      $150                No
CCC             3/1/13      $45             No
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you a list of unique `priStkCode` values for which at least one row exists with False in `priPriceConfirmed`.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT priStkCode
FROM tblPriData
WHERE priPriceConfirmed = False;
```

Then you can select the matching `tblPriData` rows with an `INNER JOIN` to that query.

```sql
SELECT pd.*
FROM
    tblPriData AS pd
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT priStkCode
        FROM tblPriData
        WHERE priPriceConfirmed = False
    ) AS sub
    ON pd.priStkCode = sub.priStkCode;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also appreciate your breaking down of how the subquery works. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 pd.priStkCode
,pd.priDate
,pd.priOrigPrice
,pd.priPriceConfirmed
FROM  
 tblPriData pd
 INNER JOIN
 (SELECT priStkCode
  FROM tblPriData
  WHERE priPriceConfirmed = No) AS subqry
    ON pd.priStkCode = subqry.priStkCode
```